# Laravel eloquent response differs from SQL return

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve some data using eloquent with custom groups

my builder:

```
return Model::whereNotNull('t.date')
            ->selectRaw("case when datediff(date(now()), t.date) between '0' and '30' then 'up_to_30'
            when datediff (date(now()), t.date) between '31' and '60' then '31_to_60'
            when datediff (date(now()), t.date) between '61' and '90' then '61_to_90'
            else 'more_than_90'
            end as report_days_info, count(t.id)")
            ->groupBy('report_days_info')
            ->get();
```

my SQL query returns the data:

| report_days_info | COUNT(t.id) |
| --- | --- |
| 31_to_60 | 1 |
| 61_to_90 | 3 |
| more_than_90 | 18 |
| up_to_30 | 3 |

but my laravel response is:

```
"data": [
    {
        "report_days_info": "more_than_90",
        "count(t.id)": 1
    },
    {
        "report_days_info": "up_to_30",
        "count(t.id)": 1
    },
    {
        "report_days_info": "31_to_60",
        "count(t.id)": 1
    }
]
```

I expected the Laravel response to be the same as the SQL query, am'I doing something wrong or this is how the response should be?

Here's a [fiddle so you can test it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a411a/1)

Comment: Possibly need to `date(t.date)`  Just a  thought? -- I don't know how Laravel does with field definitions .. a Raw SQL call will  "know" that your field is `datetime` - - Maybe Laravel doesn't?

Comment: I can't duplicate it. I loaded your table into my DB, and use `DB::table('t')->whereNotNull('t.date')....`, and got your mysql results.  Same when I created a model TestModel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code maybe?

```php
return DB::table('t')->selectRaw("
   CASE
      WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), t.date) BETWEEN '0' AND '30' THEN 'up_to_30'  
      WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), t.date) BETWEEN '31' AND '60' THEN '31_to_60' 
      WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), t.date) BETWEEN '61' AND '90' THEN '61_to_90' 
      ELSE 'more_than_90'
   END AS report_days_info, COUNT(t.id)
")
->groupBy('report_days_info')
->get();
```

Comment: with this I had the same result. Probably it's the way laravel deal with the query response. I think I'll just build a resource to deal with it